# Database Hangs while trying to run sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a challenge with SQL Server. We are running SQL with an inhouse developed  application. Lately we have been having a challenge where the DB hangs and users are unable to access the application.  Sometimes they have an error that says the system timed out when contacting the DB or the Application hangs. We thought it was the network, but now the network people say they have fixed the network but the problem continues. I am now faced with a problem where i end up restarting the server more than 10 times every day.

What else can i check?

Comment: Which SQL Server you are using? Can you provide some bit more details about your environment

Comment: What is version and edition of SQL Server and please if possible can you post contents of errorlog(sp_readerrorlog)

Comment: To feww details. Anyway, run on server the command "sp_who2" and check blocking queries. Is the server under pressure?